# adding files to svn:ignore from a script

Tags: svn, properties, ignore

I am trying to remove all the NetBeans related files (`nbactions.xml` and `nb-configuration.xml`) from a maven based tree of projects, and add them to `svn:ignore` in every directory that contains a `pom.xml` so they are not checked-in again.

As it will be cumbersome to manually do that, I'm trying to write a script to do the dirty work for me, but I'm finding that editing subversion properties is not as *batch-friendly* as adding a few lines to the good old `.cvsignore` using shell append redirection `>>`.

Oh, never mind, I've devised a solution while typing this, I'm posting it anyway to not waste the effort and in case something better comes up :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer I've thought of is to *hack* the `SVN_EDITOR` system property to be my update script rather than an interactive editor.

I haven't tried it yet, but it should be something like:

### update_svn_ignore.sh

```
cat $1 ~/filestoignore.txt | sort | uniq > tmp.txt
mv tmp.txt $1
```

and to do it in every directory with a `pom.xml`

```
export SVN_EDITOR=update_svn_ignore.sh
for PROJDIR in `find -name pom.xml | awk -F"pom.xml" '{print $1}'`; do svn propedit svn:ignore $PROJDIR; done
```